# Construction of perspective matrix

Tags: projection, perspective

Is it possible to Construct a perspective matrix by multiplying a perspective transformation with a parallel projection ? 
[image]

I want a perspective projection in 2D space which is calculated by multiplying a perspective transformation matrix with a parallel projection matrix. 
The final form should look like the image I posted above.

Comment: Sure, but if the parallel projection matrix has already flattened the depth, then you'll just get a nice perspective view of a flat plane, which may or may not be what you're going for. Can you add a bit more context about how you're constructing these matrices and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DMGregory i edited my question. Feel free to take a look.

Comment: ...you've shown the general form of 3x3 matrix multiplication, literally the least specific you could possibly be in this context. :/

Comment: The left matrix should represent a perspective projection along the negative y-axis onto the x axis with eye point R3∋A=(0,−y_0)T (T stands for Transpose). This projection can be separated into a perspective transformation followed by a parallel projection along the negative y-axis. What I should create here are the matrices for the **perspective projection**, **the corresponding perspective transformation** and **the subsequent parallel projection** in the above form. I hope I am more specific .

Comment: @DMGregory I provided more information above.